# ubuntu 17.10 reboots on resume after suspend

Tags: suspend, 17.10, reboot, wakeup

i've been searching on this topic but have not found a solution that fixes my problem. ubuntu 17.10 amd64. whenever my computer goes to sleep (plugged in or not), upon resuming, it does a hard reboot instead. let me know what info you need and how to get it.

free:

````
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        938M        4.4G        420M        2.4G        6.1G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G```
````

swapon:

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO

/dev/dm-1 partition 7.9G   0B   -1
```

here is a tail of syslog before it rebooted and after.

Before:

```
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Closed CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 colord[931]: failed to get session [pid 3914]: No data available
Dec  9 14:28:42 eric-Inspiron-7352 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="907" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
```

After reboot:

```
Dec 10 19:56:57 eric-Inspiron-7352 gnome-software[1771]: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Dec 10 19:56:57 eric-Inspiron-7352 gnome-software[1771]: g_strv_length: assertion 'str_array != NULL' failed
Dec 10 19:56:57 eric-Inspiron-7352 gnome-software[1771]: json_object_has_member: assertion 'member_name != NULL' failed
Dec 10 19:56:57 eric-Inspiron-7352 gnome-software[1771]: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Dec 10 19:56:57 eric-Inspiron-7352 gnome-software[1771]: g_strv_length: assertion 'str_array != NULL' failed
Dec 10 19:56:57 eric-Inspiron-7352 gnome-software[1771]: running refresh with timeout=60 with cache age=86400 on plugin=steam took 6018ms
Dec 10 19:56:57 eric-Inspiron-7352 gnome-software[1771]: running get-updates with refine-flags=require-update-details,require-update-severity with timeout=60 on plugin=fwupd
Dec 10 19:56:58 eric-Inspiron-7352 compiz[1679]: WARN  2017-12-10 19:56:58 unity.filemanager.gnome GnomeFileManager.cpp:69 Locations have been invalidated, maybe there's no filemanager around...
Dec 10 19:57:00 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Dec 10 19:57:00 eric-Inspiron-7352 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
```

Comment: The output of `free;swapon` will help us.

Comment: i suspended my computer after writing the post. this is the first time since my ubuntu upgrade it did not reboot on wake. i'll see what happens again after putting my computer away for the night.

Comment: it seems to happen when suspended for more than a couple of hours.

Comment: I've tried using xorg instead of wayland, and switching to gdm3 instead of lightdm, still no change. Unity, gnome, xfce.. the desktop manager doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: Using stock graphics card for dell inspiron 13 - basic intel graphics hd 5500 card.